# How to get the desirable symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How to get a matrix $A$ of order ${n\times n}$ such that one of its eigenvalue $=\frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{5})$.
Note that, $A$ must be symmetric matrix whose its diagonal entries are zer.

Answer (score 1):

Create a diagonal matrix $D$ with a required value (as many times as you need).
Take an orthogonal matrix $U$ of the same size . You get what you ask using

$$A=UDU^T$$